# mysql design tips needed when using "set" field type

Tags: mysql

I am starting a new MySQL database project where one of the key fields of the table `Organizations` will be `Town`.  A person can select multiple cities or towns here, and they can select any city or town in the entire state.  They need to be able to easily add a new town, and being able to remove a town easily would be great too.  So, since there need to be multiple values of an enumerated type, I thought the field type for `Town` should be `set`.  Then, when I define the table and the field `Town` I can enumerate all 170 towns.
But, I guess I still have to have another table that also lists all these cities and towns so I can use this in a drop down when they are selecting cities and towns for their Organization.

1. Is this the right way to do it, using the field type `set` and a separate table for the cities/towns which will match what I enumerate for this field? I will be doing lots of searches and want the searching optimized so if there's a better way to organize this, would love to know.
2. I know how, using `concat()` to add just one town to an existing list of towns for a particular Organization, (i.e. `UPDATE Organization SET Town = concat(Town, ',Springfield') WHERE OrgID = 1`) and that works great. But is there an equivalent if they have a long list of towns already specified and just want to delete one?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a SET for towns if you will frequently be adding and removing values since it would require a table ALTER for each change.

Comment: I would set Town up as a separate table, for ease of maintenance, and create a link table between organisation and town to deal with the relationships between them. As Marcus says, there's a lot of work required if you use a Set, and why do that if you don't have to?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up the relationship though when one Organization can be associated with one OR MORE towns.  How do I do that in the database?